# Pass parameter to devise sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise for user registration in my rails app. I have modified the RegistrationsController and sign up views to add Stripe integration. There are several subscription plans a user can select from a select_tag.

On my home page it displays the plans. When the user selects one and it directs them to the sign up page I want to automatically select that plan in the select_tag. I can do that using if/else statements. How do I tell my sign up view what plan the user selected on the home page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the link for each plan so that it includes a parameter in the URL.

```
<%= link_to 'Pro', signup_path(:plan => 'pro') %>
```

That would create a URL that's something like `http://example.com/signup?plan=pro`.

Then, in your sign up page, you can automatically set the value of the pull down menu to what was passed in the URL by using something like this:

```
<%= f.select :plan, @plans, :selected => params[:plan] %>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I nearly had it. I had: signup_path(params[:plan => 'pro']). Thanks for your help.